# How to exact data from MySQL in readable format C#

Tags: c#, mysql

So Day 4 in learning C#. I have built a data base before and can query that database using mysql workbench no issues and get the results I want. I am trying to get those results in visual studio code via C#. I can get as far as to pull the data and it will console write

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+ValueCollection[System.String,System.Object]
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+ValueCollection[System.String,System.Object]
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+ValueCollection[System.String,System.Object]
```

What I get in my Sql workbench when i run SELECT First_Name FROM users ; it gives me my first names no issues.

But if i use

```
 public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var thing = DbConnector.Query("SELECT First_Name FROM users ");
            foreach(var i in thing)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(i.Values);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

It gives me that system collection stuff.

I have tried i.value, and i.value.tostring() I really just need to know what method to convert the string to the value not the object.

The database is sending it over like so

public static List> Query(string queryString)

Any Help would be greatly appricated.

Comment: Values is a collection, have you tried iterating over that collection...?

Comment: var thing = DbConnector.Query("SELECT First_Name FROM users ");
            foreach(var i in thing)  thats what im doing to get all three to show up

Comment: Right, and that returns a Dictionary that contains multiple values.  So inside your loop, loop through the `Values` property of your `thing` variable

Comment: can you post how you would code it so if it works i can green check you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Values` is a `ValueCollection` property [see the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x(v=vs.110).aspx).  You will have to iterate through the values and write them to the Console if you want to see them.

```
var thing = DbConnector.Query("SELECT First_Name FROM users ");
foreach(var i in thing)
{
    foreach(var item in thing.Values)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
        System.Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I got it done becore you did that but yes that works and Ill green arror itfor you